# Post export SVN script, possibly with TortoiseSVN that renames exported files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, export

Been searching and reading for this solution, but didn't find one. Or not the best one. What i would like to achieve:

In our SVN Server, we will use tags as project official releases. At some point, we will export the latest tag folder, which will contain all documents that have been tagged till then for Assessment. When the export is done, documents exported would have to get renamed with latest tag added in the end of the file name. Here is a small example, let's say that file was in tag folder #6 (again, that is latest tag).

File in SVN tag folder 6:
GEN_Software_Component_Design_Specification_Application_Module_SRV.docx

File after being exported:
GEN_Software_Component_Design_Specification_Application_Module_SRV_06.docx

I know TortoiseSVN Client Hook scripts don't have post export option. So is a simple batch script the only solution here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a task for a build or deployment server which exactly can do such things. Or you can use the simple script solution as well.

Comment: What do you mean, can you be a bit more specific? Thank you.

Comment: Let a build server do the work. Use for example Hudson and write a script which will do the particular steps (renaming etc.) and use it from inside Hudson (or other CI Systems).

Comment: Decided to make some easy to use program, since i have no clue about those server settings,steps or what ever :)